# How to retrieve an Enum key via variable

Tags: python, variables, enums

I'm new to python. Is it possible to get the value of an `Enum` key from a variable key?

```
class Numbering(Enum):
 a=2
 b=3

key = "b"
print(Numbering.key)
#the result I want is 3
```

Comment: I've (quickly, I admit) searched for obvious duplicates but couldn't find a proper one so all have an upvote.

Comment: I bet not to use `Enum` at all. You can easily maintain a `dict`

Comment: yes, i was hoping to find the duplicate as well (i know there must be plenty, maybe the choice of a title is what's different). i know how to do this in C# 
Enum.Parse(typeof(EnumNameHere), KeyVal);
but since I'm new to python I haven't found a reliable documentation source yet.

Comment: @adamkim The official Python docs are actually very good, for example: https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#programmatic-access-to-enumeration-members-and-their-attributes

Answer (score 19, accepted):

One of the many neat features of Python's `Enum`s is retrieval by name:

```
>>> print(Numbering[key])
Numbering.b
```

and for the value:

```
>>> print(Numbering[key].value)
3
```